# How to write a code to detect how many times the IR detector has detected an IR signal.... HELP

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to write a code so that I can detect how many times the IR detector has detected the IR signal from the IR transmitter.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE. What have you managed to do so far?. You might find this helpful: [How to ask a good question for Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/how-to-ask-a-good-question-for-arduino-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple:

```
IRDetectorLibraryObject ir;
int counter = 0;

void setup()
{
    ir.setup();
}
void loop ()
{
    if (ir.detectedSignal())
    {
      ++counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course all that relies on you having an IR detector library like the one i imagined you had, and you only wanting to count the detections and never know what the value is, but apart from that...

Comment: It would be great if you can also give us the circuit diagram...

Comment: The compiler says it cannot recognize the data type of IRDetectorLibraryObject

Comment: It wont recognise it because you need to find one that is compatible with your hardware and use that name instead.  As for a circuit diagram that depends on you hardware, if you don't specify that then I can only guess that you need to plug the wires from the IR detector into a microprocessor, and you might want to power the uP from a 5v source, but your hardware may be different to the hardware I am imagining you have.